# Multiple Categories in .NET PropertyGrid are not visible with Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid, categories

I have a PropertyGrid with 2 Categories: "Customer Test 1" and "Customer Test 2"

If I have only ONE CategoryAttribute in the BrowseableAttributes ONE Category is shown.
If I have BOTH/TWO CategoryAttribute`s in the BrowseableAttributes NONE category is shown.

Why that?

```
public class Customer
    {
        [DisplayName("first name...:")]
        [Category("Customer Test 1")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("number...")]
        [Category("Customer Test 1")]
        public int Number { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("wage...:")]
        [Category("Customer Test 2")]
        public int Wage { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("description...:")]
        [Category("Customer Test 1")]
        public string  Desc { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("shit...:")]
        [Category("Customer Test 1")]
        public string Nonsens { get; set; }      
    }

    public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                Attribute[] attributes = new Attribute[]{ new CategoryAttribute("Customer Test 1"), new CategoryAttribute("Customer Test 2") };
                propertyGrid1.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(attributes);

                propertyGrid1.PropertySort = PropertySort.Categorized;
                propertyGrid1.ToolbarVisible = true;
                propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Customer() { FirstName = "Bernd", Number = 100, Desc = 

"steine", Wage = 3333, Nonsens = "crap" };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that if you assign multiple attributes to BrowsableAttributes, properties need to have only 1 matching attribute and not ALL of them?

In other words, BrowsableAttributes might act as a filter using and AND operator on the attributes instead of an OR. But I have to admit that I have not tried this myself.

Comment: found the limitation although it doesnt make sense... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/707ebb7f-0a76-40d9-9e0c-31183d454d90 Do you know wether it is possible to say somewhow to the propertygrid to display only properties which ARE annotated? The other way round...

Comment: This is accurate, check TypeConverter.GetProperties().

Comment: sorry Hans, but what is accurate?

Comment: @Peladao But... with an AND both Categories should be shown  ;-)

Comment: @hans with your TypeConverter.GetProperties() Method do I have to touch anyhow my business class (this I do not want/not allowed) ?

Comment: @msfanboy but how can one property belong to 2 categories at the same time?

Comment: @Hans: Right, it says "An array of type Attribute that is used as a filter." I read something similar elsewhere.

Comment: @Peladao Have I said that? I want 2 categories at the same time :)

Comment: @msfanboy I know, I was just saying that if the BrowsableAttributes effectively works as an AND filter (which it seems to do according to the specs -although not very clearly described) then you can never show two categories at the same time that are specified in BrowsableAttributes. The solution you found also confirms that. Anyway, glad it's solved. Always lots of fun that propertygrid :)

Comment: @Peladao I have not found yet any solution, just a way to get there ;-) via TypeConverter.GetProperties()